# Forms Authentication Cookie - Why SSL?

Tags: asp.net, security

I see the guidance when using formsAuthentication in ASP.NET is to use SSL via the requireSSL property.

I was under the impression that the contents of the cookie are encrypted. So I'm trying to grasp why SSL is required as well?

Comment: interestingly though the default is false! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685502/why-is-the-default-for-formsauthentications-requiressl-property-false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the cookie that's the problem, it's sending the username and password. Using SSL will stop that transaction being intercepted (and provides some measure of reassurance if users would ever bother checking the certificate *grin*)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exact question!

I'm somewhat satisfied with @blowdart's answer for sites where there isn't sensitive information visible when you're logged in.
Absolutely definitely you should be logging in over SSL - but also if someone gets access to your cookie they can impersonate you until it expires.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998310.aspx

> To prevent forms authentication cookies from being captured and
>   tampered with while crossing the
>   network, ensure that you use SSL with
>   all pages that require authenticated
>   access and restrict forms
>   authentication tickets to SSL channels
>   by setting requireSSL="true" on the
>    element.
>
> To restrict forms authentication cookies to SSL channels
>
> Set requireSSL="true" on the  element, as shown in the
>   following code.
>
> By setting requireSSL="true", you set the secure cookie property that
>   determines whether browsers should
>   send the cookie back to the server.
>   With the secure property set, the
>   cookie is sent by the browser only to
>   a secure page that is requested using
>   an HTTPS URL.
>
> Note:   If you are using cookieless sessions, you must ensure that the
>   authentication ticket is never
>   transmitted across an unsecured
>   channel.